# uninitialized constant with siteprism

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am getting the following error message

`uninitialized constant PageObjects::Sections::HomePage::SitePrism (NameError)
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/sections/home_page/navigation_bar.rb:4:in <module:HomePage>
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/sections/home_page/navigation_bar.rb:3:in <module:Sections>
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/sections/home_page/navigation_bar.rb:2:in <module:PageObjects>
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/sections/home_page/navigation_bar.rb:1:in <top (required)>
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/home_page.rb:1:in require_relative
/Users/fee/Desktop/Shafiq/audiobook-collection-manager-acceptance/features/page_objects/home_page.rb:1:in <top (required)>`

This is the code it is related too:

require_relative 'sections/home_page/navigation_bar'

`module PageObjects
     class HomePage < SitePrism::Page
         section :navigation_bar, PageObjects::Sections::HomePage::NavigationBar, 
         '.nav-sprite-v1 nav-bluebeacon'
     end
end`

`module PageObjects
    module Sections
        module HomePage
            class NavigationBar < SitePrism::Section
                element :your_acc_btn, '.nav-a nav-a-2'
            end
        end
    end
end`

I am having issues issues locating the navigation bar class but i'm not sure where I am going wrong can somebody please help.

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB6t8.png)

Comment: Could you please format your code snippets.

Comment: I have done please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require 'site_prism'` prior to your `require_relative` or earlier.

Normally missing constant errors can be highly confusing as they will show the module lookup from the position that was called.  Not the name that you have typed `SitePrism::Page`

Example of the Constant lookup error message.

```
class Party
  def self.now
    Hard
  end
end

Party.now # => NameError: uninitialized constant Party::Hard
```

Note that the error message the is presented does references the first layer of the constant lookup, not the root constant that we probably wanted.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. :-) I was stuck on this issue for ages.